# Динамическое добавление ссылок на страницу в JSF из БД

Tags: java, база-данных, jsf

У себя в проекте на JSF использую bootfaces, компонент:

```
<b:listLinks>
<b:navLink href="....xhtml" value="name1" />
<b:navLink href="....xhtml" value="name2" />
</b:listLinks>
```

В БД есть таблица со списком: название - адрес.
Как реализовать динамическое построения списка ссылок на страницы из БД?
То есть добавляю ссылку в таблицу и при перезагрузки страницы он появляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На [демонстрационной странице](http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/layout/navLinks.jsf) используемого Вами фреймворка есть пример `Sidebar using ui:repeat`, думаю, это именно то, что Вам нужно. Вот немного переработанный пример с их сайта:

```
<b:listLinks>
  <ui:repeat var="musicStyle" value="#{navLinkBean.musicStyles}">
    <b:navLink href="#{musicStyle.link}" value="#{musicStyle.name}" />
  </ui:repeat>
</b:listLinks>
```

`navLinkBean.musicStyles` должен возвращать список ссылок. `musicStyle` - это экземпляр объекта из списка, он должен содержать "*название - адрес*" в полях `name` и `link` соответственно.

PS Настоятельно рекомендую ознакомится **со всеми компонентами** фреймворка на его демонстрационной странице перед началом работы с ним, хотя бы вскользь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! То что нужно. Вроде много раз просматривал и читал страницу, а этот момент ускользнул. Только осваиваю технологию.